# Why do I get two icons for my application after an upgrade?

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

I created an Android application and published it on the Android Market.

When I upgrade to higher version, then do update to my phone, there are now two application icons for my application.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Applications are identified using package name. You must have used 2 different package name for both applications.

or 2 different entry points in your manifest
in that case check whetehr you have specified launcher for 2 activities in your application as below. if so only allow the entery point of your application to have launcher.

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: ah, I see, but my problem is different, I have changed default activity by "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER", when I update app, It still display 2 same icons

Comment: why dont you try unnistall the app and install it again?

Comment: remove the <intent-filer> tag for all activities except the main entry point activity.

Comment: I mean that my user look my app so strange because there is 2 icon of it, uninstall is ok with me but not with my user

Comment: provide a update to your application to the market with the fix, it'll replace the existing app in your users' phone with the new app which will remove the multiple issue problem.